# GCC installed but not showing on OSX 10.9.5

Tags: xcode, gcc, installation, clang

I had a working gcc/g++(2 month back;can't remember) from terminal of my mavericks with Xcode & Command Line Tools 6.0.1(6A317) but its not working now(might be due to minor OS upgrade). I tried all the commands gcc, g++, clang but neither of them works. Again, I tried installing using MacPorts using `sudo port install gcc49` and it completed successfully but still any of the commands doesn't works(even after restarting terminal).

Additional Information- When I look for gcc/g++ in /usr/bin/, there is only alias present. 
But clang++ and clang are present in /usr/bin/.

Comment: Reinstall Xcode, and make sure you check the box for "unix development support" or something like that. That tells Xcode to put the necessary files in /usr/bin so you can use it from the command line. Also, check to make sure /usr/bin is actually in your path.

Comment: At present, /usr/bin is in the path and for now clang++ is working.